# Using environment variable in mosquitto configuration file

Tags: config, mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to set remote_client ID using a value from the system environment variables instead of hardcoding it in the mosquitto.conf configuration file.

Is it possible to pass it inline when starting mosquitto such as:

```
mosquitto -remote_clientid $envar
```

Or can I refer environment variables directly from inside the config file?

```
remote_clientid $envar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested this, but you can run `mosquitto` with `-c CONFIGFILE`, so if you don't want to change your actual `mosquitto.conf` on disk, you should be able to use a *"process substitution"* to pass a modified copy of your conf file like this in `bash`:

```
mosquitto -c <(sed "s/remote_clientid=.*/remote_clientid=$CONFIGVAR" /etc/mosquitto.conf)
```

Note that this is a *bash-ism* so you need to be using `bash` shell.

Comment: thanks a lot, that's pretty convenient, anyways I was doing echo $SET_REMOTE_CLIENTID >> mosquitto.conf, but yours is certainly much better

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the only way to do this currently is to programmatically edit `mosquitto.conf` ([this project](https://github.com/efrecon/docker-mosquitto) uses that approach to allow support for configuration via environment variables in docker).

There is no command line option to set `remote_clientid` and environment variables are not supported in the `mosquitto.conf` (but this may change - see [this feature request](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/2203)).

Comment: Shouldnt that feature request be for original mosquitto project, I mean  yes they could modify the original source for mosquitto in their fork but its certainly not a dockerfile level feature

Comment: Not sure what you mean - the feature request is on `github.com/eclipse/mosquitto` (the official repo - see [link here](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/iot.mosquitto/developer)). The other project linked provides a demonstration of a workaround (generating `mosquitto.conf` from environmental variables).

Comment: oh ,sorry I got confused